# Differentiate between mouse scroll and two finger trackpad scroll

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, mouseevent, mousewheel

I am trying to differentiate between a user scrolling using the wheel on a mouse and using two fingers on a trackpad. Currently I am checking if the wheelDelta is either 120, 180, or 240. If it is, it's usually a mouse wheel. This works most of the time but occasionally happens with a two finger scroll. This also might not work if a user has a mouse with a different wheelDelta. Does anyone know of a better solution?